# The variable needs an initializer c++?

Tags: c++

How do I initialize convert.gram? Whenever I define "gram" in the class decleration the program responds appropriatly. Im trying to put gram in the constructor but its not working. Also am I structuring everything right? Thanks for the help!

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

struct grams{
    grams();
    float converter(float pounds);

    float gram;
    float pounds;
    float answer;
    };

    float grams::converter(float pounds){
    answer = pounds * gram;
    return answer;
    }

    grams::grams(){
    float convert.gram = 453.592;
    }

int main(){
    float PtC;
    grams convert;

    cout<<"Pound to Gram Converter \n";
    cout<<"How Many Pounds Do You Want to Convert? \n";

    cin>>PtC;

    float converter = convert.converter(PtC);

    cout<<"Answer = "<<converter<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
C:/Users/lisa/Desktop/codelight c++/time_of_for_loop/for_loop_time/for_loop_time/main.cpp:31:13: error: expected initializer before '.' token
```

Comment: `float convert.gram = 453.592;` what do you want to happen here?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x The program converts pounds to grams. I will extend the program so I want to organize it using classes. Im having trouble with that line. The line is to set "gram" to 453.592 in the constructor whenever a new instance of grams is converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is just set `gram`; `convert` is a instance of `grams` so its field will be set properly.

```
grams::grams(){
    gram = 453.592;
}
```

But the more conventional and performant way to initialize class members is to use a member initializer list, like so:

```
grams::grams() : gram(453.592) {

}
```

Also, a bit of advice: Because you are using `gram` as a constant, it would make more sense to set it as a constant instead of a member. You can set it as a static member (and name it better)

```
struct grams {
    static const float GRAMS_PER_POUND = 453.592;
    ...
```

You also aren't using the member `pound` at all; you should consider removing it. There also doesn't make much sense to store `answer` because you aren't using it via `convert` after the `converter` function completes.